# Matrix sieve algorithm

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I proposed "matrix sieve" algorithm for finding primes as two pairs of 2-dimensional arrays: 
positive integers which do not appear in these 
arrays are indexes $k$ of primes in the sequences $S1(k)=6k-1$  and $S2(k)=6k+1$.

Positive integers which do not appear in both arrays $
  A1(i,j)=6i^2 + (6i-1)(j-1)$ and $A2(i,j)=6i^2 + (6i+1)(j-1)$

```
                            |  6   11    16     21   ...|
                A1(i,j) =   | 24   35     46    57   ...|
                            | 54   71     88   105   ...|
                            | 96  119    142   165   ...|
                            |...  ...  ...   ...     ...|


                             |  6    13   20    27   ...|
                 A2(i,j) =   | 24    37   50    63   ...|
                             | 54    73   92   111   ...|
                             | 96   121  146   171   ...|
                             |...      ...       ...        ...   ...|
```

are indexes $k$ of primes in the sequence $S1(k)=6k-1$ .

Positive integers which do not appear in both arrays $
  A3(i,j)=6i^2-2i + (6i-1)(j-1)$ and $A4(i,j)=6i^2 +2i+ (6i+1)(j-1)$

```
                                   | 4       9     14       19.. |
                                   |20      31     42       53...|
                                   |48      65     82       99...|
                          A3(i,j)= |88     111     134     157...|
                                   |...   ...      ...     ...   |

                            | 8      15      22     29 ..|
                            |28     41       54     67...|
                   A4(i,j)= |60     79       98     117..|
                            |104   129      154    179...|
                            |...    ...     ...     ...  |
```

are indexes $k$ of primes in the sequence $S2(k)=6k+1$. 
Since all primes (except 2 and 3) are in  one of two forms $6k-1$ or $6k+1$ so we
can find primes simply by picking up positive integers which do not appear in these arrays.(C++ code see http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/BrowseCategoryOrSearchResults.asp?lngWId=3&blnAuthorSearch=TRUE&lngAuthorId=21687209&strAuthorName=Boris%20Sklyar&txtMaxNumberOfEntriesPerPage=25

My question is:    Does proposed "matrix sieve" algorithm  suitable as an alternative for 
sieve of Eratosthеnes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix sieve theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293684/matrix-sieve-theorem)

Comment: As explained in the linked question, this is more or less equivalent to iterating over all $x, y \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 6$ to eliminate $xy$ as a prime and therefore not a useful alternative to the sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: In practice  proposed algorithm is useful: it allows to calculate primes in the range 10^6 for numbers up to 10^20  for run time <10s on an ordinary laptop.(see link)

Comment: there is a much simpler and probably faster method to determine, not which number is prime, but which number is a composite in the arithmetic progression $(6k+1)$ and $(6k-1)$. Once we know which numbers are composite, we can determine which are primes. see answer # 2 here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549239/counting-primes-by-counting-numbers-of-the-form-6k-pm-1-which-are-not-prime/3108962#3108962

Comment: If you look closely at arrays A1-A4 then you can see that these arrays are general expression of composite numbers (except divisible by 2 and 3) see   [link] (_https://www.academia.edu/13890086/Matrix_sieve_the_easiest_way_to_find_prime_numbers_) so we are discussing the same method

Comment: My C++ code program finds primes in a range of one million for numbers up to 10^20 in run time of 10 sec  (C++ code  see [link] (_https://www.academia.edu/13890086/Matrix_sieve_the_easiest_way_to_find_prime_numbers_) and how fast is your program?

Comment: See also [link](_http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/BrowseCategoryOrSearchResults.asp?lngWId=3&blnAuthorSearch=TRUE&lngAuthorId=21687209&strAuthorName=Boris%20Sklyar&txtMaxNumberOfEntriesPerPage=25_)